# socket io broadcast stop working after 2 attempt

Tags: node.js, socket.io

```
socket.broadcast.to("room1").emit('remove_card_success', "Hiii");
```

works only 2 times, after that it is calling `Adapter.prototype.del` from socket Lib and nothing emitted.

`Adapter.prototype.del` removed one socket connection | socket id

What should be next step to emit data successfully ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if you have leave Room | channel somewhere in your code like,

```
socket.leave(currentRoomId);
```